# android:textAppearance in TextView

Tags: android

If i specify the TextView like this, why I am getting a 'white on white'? I am running 
Isn't TextView on Android is black by default? I am running on Nexus One.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/atext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are changing the `Background` of the parent view, but really desire to invert the `Theme` of the entire Application.

If my assumption is correct, what you want to do it add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml `application` tag - `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"`.

Eg:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go into Eclipse click on the text view then go over properties you can see a huge list of options